# Oracle d/b Create Index error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting missing expression on the below sql when running in sql developer (though i believe it has nothing to do with oracle client) though everything seems to be all right.

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CRIS2"."SYS_IL0000296692C00014$$" ON "CRIS2"."AOITARGETPOINT" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIOSIRTDATA" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) ;

--------------------------------------------------
Error starting at line 1 in command:
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CRIS2"."SYS_IL0000296692C00014$$" ON "CRIS2"."AOITARGETPOINT" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIOSIRTDATA" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) 
Error at Command Line:2 Column:2
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help pls?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing column list in CREATE INDEX statement

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CRIS2"."SYS_IL0000296692C00014$$" ON "CRIS2"."AOITARGETPOINT" 
  (-->Field List<--)
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIOSIRTDATA" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) ;
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the suggestion.That works now.Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Pakhantsov mentioned, the missing field list is obviously the biggest problem.  But there are some other issues with this statement.

You may want to give the index a real name instead of using the system generated name.  It's probably just a style issue, but it can be confusing if you create objects that start with SYS.  (Or is there a possibility of another object name colliding with this?  I'm not sure how Oracle comes up with its names.)

`PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0);` is the parallel clause syntax from Oracle 7.  The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#i2159323) warns "The syntax of the parallel_clause supersedes syntax appearing in earlier releases of Oracle. Superseded syntax is still supported for backward compatibility but may result in slightly different behavior from that documented."  In my testing I haven't found any issues with this syntax, but you should still probably avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you suggestions Jonearles